# Read a file's content (with spaces) into an array

Tags: arrays, shell

I'm creating a Shell Script, and I have a file like this called `expressions.txt`:

```
"Ploink Poink"
"I Need Oil"
"Some Bytes are Missing!"
"Poink Poink"
"Piiiip Beeeep!!"
"Whoops! I'm out of memory!"
"1 + 1 = 3"
"Please fix my bugs!"
"Goeiedag!"
"Hallo!"
"Guten Tag!"
"Hyvää Päivää!"
"Добрый день"
"!สวัสดี"
"Bonjour!"
"!مرحبا"
"!שלום"
"Γειά!"
```

I have this code in `robot.sh`:

```
expressions=( $(cat expressions.txt) )

# Get random expression...
selectedexpression=${expressions[$RANDOM % ${#expressions[@]}]}

# Write to Shell
echo $selectedexpression
```

However, this splits the file's content by spaces, not by quotes, so the output could be something like `"Ploink`, `Need` or `fix`. But I want the complete sentences. Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Oh, the shell I use is `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: you probably want to mention what shell you're targetting.  plain sh, bash, csh?  Or maybe windows powershell ;) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work with `bash`, possibly with `sh`:

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
expressions=()
while read line
do
  expressions=("${expressions[@]}" "$line")
done < expressions.txt
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

Answer (score 0):

use (g)awk, or nawk on Solaris

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand() }
{
  lines[++d]=$0    
}END{
  RANDOM = int(1 + rand() * d)
  print lines[RANDOM]
}' expression.txt
```